# Como pasar maxBytesPerRead en python

Tags: python, c#, api, soap, binding

Tengo un codigo Python que llama un API Soap sin problemas.

Cuando executo el API enviando un gran XML, este falla dandome el siguiente error:

The 'maximum bytes per Read operation' quota (4096) has been exceeded while reading XML data.

Del lado del serivdor el parametro del binding maxBytesPerRead esta maximizado.

Para hacer una prueba, hice un codigo C# e hice el mismo push de los datos, y este funciona. Como del lado de mi cliente .net tengo un app.config el cual puedo agregar el parametro que requiero, este funciona sin problemas.

Existe esto desde Python?

Aqui hay un ejemplo de mi codigo:

```
import requests
url = https://ApplicationURL.com/ApplicationWebServices/BlueWebService.svc/file
payload = """<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:arr="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays" xmlns:blue="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Blue.Integration">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <tem:TransactionId>000000000</tem:TransactionId>
      <tem:DataBlockName>BlockName</tem:DataBlockName>
      <tem:ColumnNamesList>
             <arr:string>CourseID</arr:string>
             <arr:string>UserID_1</arr:string>
      </tem:ColumnNamesList>
      <tem:APIKeyHeader>123456789</tem:APIKeyHeader>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
        <tem:DataObjectTransferRequestV2>
        <tem:Data>
            <blue:IDataRow>
               <blue:IDataRowValue>
                  <blue:IDataObj>
                     <blue:IDataObjValue>Math004</blue:IDataObjValue>
                  </blue:IDataObj>
                  <blue:IDataObj>
                     <blue:IDataObjValue>User4</blue:IDataObjValue>
                  </blue:IDataObj>
               </blue:IDataRowValue>
            </blue:IDataRow>
         </tem:Data>
</tem:DataObjectTransferRequestV2>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>"""
headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'text/xml;charset=UTF-8',
  'SOAPAction': '"http://tempuri.org/IBlueWebService/PushObjectDataV2"'
}
response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data = payload)
print(response.text.encode('utf8'))
```

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Sería bueno poder ver qué estás usando en el código python para que puedas recibir una respuesta útil.

Comment: Muchas gracias, tienes razon. Acabo de editar la pregunta y agregar el codigo Python